# Turning 1's and 0's to a list of characters in Prolog

Tags: prolog

I have a homework assignment using prolog and I'm translating a set of 1's and 0's to a different set of characters. For example, here are my facts

```
analog([1], .). 
analog([1, 1, 1], -).
analog([0], "").
analog([0, 0, 0], ^).
analog([0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0], #).
```

An example input would be a list like

```
  [1,1,1,0,1,1,1,
  0,0,0,1,1,1,0,1,1,1,0,1,1,1,0,0,0,1,0,1,1,1,
  0,1,0,0,0,1,0,1,0,1,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,
  1,1,1,0,1,0,1,1,1,0,1,0,0,0,1,1,1,0,1,1,1,
  0,1,1,1]
```

I have the following code :

```
signal_morse([], []). %base case 
signal_morse([A, B, C | Rest, R) :- 
  analog([A, B, C], H), 
  signal_morse(Rest, T), 
  append([H], T, R).
```

It only currently checks the first three elements in a list and I want to be able to check for 1 element if the first three don't match with any of the facts.

For example, say I have [1, 0, 0], since that doesn't match with any of my rules I want the program to check [1] instead and keep looking through the rest of the list.

So I wanted to know if there is any sort of pattern matching I can do so if the code `analog([A, B, C], H)` fails to find a match, the code would then try to match just the first character like `analog([A], H)`.

Comment: If you have the sequence `[1, 1, 1]` are both `[.]` and `[-, -, -]` considered  valid translations?

Comment: If  you use `'0'` and `'1'` in place of `0` and `1` you could write `[1,1,1]` more compactly as `"111"`. You only need to say `:- set_prolog_flag(double_quotes, chars).`

Comment: @lurker sorry I forgot to add that the `analog([0], "")` marker is used to distinguish `[1]` from `[1, 1, 1]`. so if given a `[1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1]` , the correct output should be `[-,"", -]` not `[ ., ., ., "", ., ., .]`

Comment: What if you have `[1, 1, 1, 1, 1]`? Is the result supposed to be `[-, ., .]` even though there's no "marker"?

Comment: so the result should be `[-]`, this is the issue I'm going through right now, if the given list does not match any of my facts, then I want to shorten the list to read the first 4 characters instead and if that still does not match, I'll read the first 3 characters.

Comment: That's a little perplexing. Why should `[1, 1, 1, 1, 1]` only yield `[-]`, leaving two more 1's in the sequence untranslated? What's the rule for whether this should occur?

Comment: Sorry, I haven't been very clear, here are the instructions regarding, from my professors instructions : `[1, 1]` could either be interpreted as `[1]`, or `[1, 1, 1]` and expects the program to try both possibilities. So we first interpret `[1, 1]` as `[1]`, then as `[1, 1, 1]`. The same is true for `[0, 0]` where it is first interpreted as `[0]`, then as `[0, 0, 0]`. Does make sense?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I realize this probably doesn't help you with your homework, but this is such a perfect problem for DCGs I can't help but show you what it would look like.

```
analog(.) --> [1].
analog(-) --> [1,1,1].
analog("") --> [0].
analog(^) --> [0,0,0].
analog(#) --> [0,0,0,0,0,0,0].

analogs([]) --> [].
analogs([A|As]) --> analog(A), analogs(As).
```

Usage:

```
?- phrase(analogs(X), [1,1,1,0,1,1,1, 0,0,0,1,1,1,0,1,1,1,0,1,1,1,0,0,0,1,0,1,1,1, 0,1,0,0,0,1,0,1,0,1,0,0,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,0,0, 1,1,1,0,1,0,1,1,1,0,1,0,0,0,1,1,1,0,1,1,1, 0,1,1,1]).
X = ['.', '.', '.', "", '.', '.', '.', "", ""|...] ;
```

Anyway, to answer your actual question, Prolog can figure out the lengths on its own with something like this:

```
signal_morse([], []).
signal_morse(Signals, [Code|RemainingMorseCodes]) :-
    append(Signal, RemainingSignals, Signals),
    analog(Signal, Code),
    signal_morse(RemainingSignals, RemainingMorseCodes).
```

Comment: Thanks, but is there anyway for it to chunk up all the consecutive ones together? Like instead of getting `[.,.,.]` for `[1, 1, 1]`, I want to get `[-]`? Does that make sense?

Comment: Did you try the code? It will produce that along with the other solutions. There isn’t any reason for it to prefer that, but you could swap the rules for those and it would prefer the hyphen rule.

Comment: So I run `signal_morse(S, [1, 1, 1]).` and that causes the program to freeze before it closes out. I'm running the program on gnu prolog, does that have anything to do with it? I'm assuming `[Code|RemainingMorseCodes]` is the input list, is that correct?

Comment: @guillermop no, the input list is signals. It's conventional for input to come before output in the most common calling conventions. Use the `signal_morse/2` from my answer with your `analog/2` database and it works in GNU Prolog.

Comment: thanks so much ! it is working now. Now this is probably a dumb question but what does Signal stand for in `append(Signal, RemainingSignals, Signals)` ? I'm very new to prolog (as you can probably tell) so I'm a bit confused by what Signal and RemainingSignals stand for.

Comment: `append/3` is commonly used to append two things to produce a third with the two concatenated. But it can also be used to tear one thing into two pieces, which is what I'm doing here. Try `append(X, Y, [1,2,3,4])` in the console and see what it does. :)

Comment: ohh man it all makes sense now, thank you so much you're a total life saver! :)